# How to calculate average percentage change using groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to create a dateframe that calculates the average percentage change over a time period.

Target dataframe would look like this:

```
|   | City | Ave_Growth |
|---|------|------------|
| 0 | A    | 0.0        |
| 1 | B    | -0.5       |
| 2 | C    | 0.5        |
```

While simplified, real data would be cities with average changes over past 7 days.

Original dataset, df_bycity, looks like this:

```
|   | City | Date       | Case_Num |
|---|------|------------|----------|
| 0 | A    | 2020-01-01 | 1        |
| 1 | A    | 2020-01-02 | 1        |
| 2 | A    | 2020-01-03 | 1        |
| 3 | B    | 2020-01-01 | 3        |
| 4 | C    | 2020-01-03 | 3        |
```

While simplified, this represents real data. Some cities have fewer cases, some have more. In some cities, there will be days that have no reported cases. But I would like to calculate average change from last seven days from today. I've simplified.

I tried the following code but I'm not getting the results I want:

`df_bycity.groupby(['City','Date']).pct_change()`

```
Case_Num
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
4   NaN
```

Obviously I'm using either pct_change or groupby incorrectly. I'm just learning this.

Anyone can point me to the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: Apparently there's no column `Date` in your dataframe. What is the output of `print('Date' in df_bycity.columns)`?

Comment: why is the percentage change for `B` -0.5 and for `C` 0.5 ?

Comment: @luigigi basically what i wanted was to average daily pct change. so for B it should be NaN, -1,0 and averaging should result in -0.5

Comment: need to edit the question.

Comment: @Erfan it says True. I did have to change the question.